# conditional formatting based on the cell above

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with several numbers one below the other, I would like to color the cells based on the cells above, example if cell is larger than cell above then the cell color is green, if it is smaller the color is red.
I need to do this in an entire column using only one formula, as this formula would be, I believe it is using = indirect with = address but I can't formulate it

Comment: you can apply the formula and populate an adjacent column to be marked with color to be filled, later with conditional formatting update the cell colors.
ex : =IF(F5>=F4, "GREEN", "RED")

Answer (score 4):

You want to create a new conditional formatting (CF) rule using relative references. Lets say A1 is your header and A2 to A100 is data. Colour all your data red with normal formatting.  Now select **A3** to A100 and create a new CF rule using a formula (last option in the "New Rule..." CF type list). In the formula text box, enter:

```
=A2<A3
```

And set the CF colour to green. Et voilà!

Comment: @MVO if this worked for you kindly checkmark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select the range you want to format and Go to **Home**- **Conditional Formatting**- **Manage Rules...**- select **Use a formula to determine with cells to format** and enter these formulas and formatting:

[image]